# Comparing every odd and even rows in excel

Tags: excel

I have a very long column of strings in an excel file. I want to compare every odd and even row together. i.e to compare cells A1 and A2, then A3 and A4, then A5 and A6, etc. I do not want to split it into two separate worksheets, one containing odd number rows and the other one containing even row numbers.
Any help on this, please?

Comment: Do you want a Formula? Do you want a VBA code? Do you want a Conditional Formatting?  Without more detil, this is impossible to answer

Comment: Sorry, Chris, I saw your comment very late and I am sorry about it. I was looking for a formula, and I gt it here. So sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula below. You start at row 2. Check if it is an even row then compare it with the above odd row

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(), 2)=0,A1=A2,"")
```

[image]

Update as requirement from comments, firstly, you have to insert the blank row for the formula to get value B1:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(), 2)=0,A2=A3,B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, How about if I want FALSE and TRUE to be written for all cells, not every another one

Comment: You just drag to copy the formula to columns C, D, E,... basically for every column you want to compare. You have the formula for each. Could you update your question with the excel sheet to tell exactly the result you want?

Comment: I do not want to fill the other columns. I just want the following cells B1, B3, B5, .... to be filled too (I mean empty cells in the B column)

Comment: Ok your question is to compare A1 and A2, then A3 and A4. NOT A2 and A3.  So, that is why I have an if to check. If you want to compare A2 and A3. Just remove that IF.

Comment: I do not want to fill the other columns. I just want the following cells B1, B3, B5, .... to be filled too (I mean empty cells in the B column). In fact, the identical cells in the A column get values in the corresponding cells in the B column. I mean B1 and B2 to be assigned FALSE, B3 and B4 to be assigned TRUE, etc.

Comment: Updated in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Please mark it as accepted answer lol